# Сохранить авторизацию в ЛК после закрытия браузера

Tags: php, opencart

Подскажите, как это реализовать для Opencart ver.2.2

Comment: Используйте cookies для этого

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

в `\catalog\controller\common\header.php` в самом начале метода install()

```
if(isset($this->session->data['customer_id'])){
        setcookie('yourstore_user_id',$this->session->data['customer_id'],time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60), true);
    }elseif(isset($_COOKIE['yourstore_user_id'])){
        $this->session->data['customer_id'] = $_COOKIE['yourstore_user_id'];
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
```

Дополнительный рефреш это конечно минус, но по крайней мере решение не зависит от движка

Answer (score 0):

В файле `system/library/session.php` найдите код:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
```

Вместо 0 укажите нужное время в секундах.

Comment: сессионные куки не сохраняются после закрытия клиента